# Finite product of compact subspaces is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am working through an old qualifying exam and I have run into what I think is a very simple question but the way it is posed is confusing to me and I am worried I a missing the point.  The question is:

Assume as known that a finite product of compact spaces is itself compact.  Let $K_i$ be a compact subspace of the space $X_i$, $i=1,...,n$.  Show that $K_1\times...\times K_n$ is a compact subspace of $X_1\times...\times X_n$.

This seems like a silly question.

It is my understanding that a subspace of a space is compact iff it is a compact space in the subspace topology.  So since each $K_i$ is a compact subspace, each $K_i$ is a compact space in the subspace topology.  But we are to assume that finite products of compact spaces are compact.  Hence, $K_1\times...\times K_n$ is a compact space in the subspace topology, so a compact subspace of $X_1\times...\times X_n$.

Is there something more subtle going on here that I am missing?

Comment: I agree with your analysis. It looks utterly tautological.

Comment: My point exactly!  I am glad I am not the only one.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip It's not tautological, albeit easy: you need to be sure that if $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$, then the product topology on $A\times B$ and the relative topology from $X\times Y$ coincide.

Comment: @egreg Well, $\epsilon$ away from tautological.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something does seem rather strange in the question as stated.  It might be more convincing to actually *prove* what the statement is telling you to assume.  It's actually not hard to prove that $K_1 \times \ldots \times K_n$ is compact in $X_1 \times \ldots \times X_n$ provided that each $K_i \subseteq X_i$ is compact.  Let $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i \; | \; i \in I\}$ be some open cover for $K_1 \times \ldots \times K_n$, and note that this induces an open cover for each $K_j$, namely we can write $\mathcal{U}_j = \{U_i \cap X_j \; | \; i \in I\}$.  This induces a finite subcover over $K_j$ by picking out some finite set of indices $I_j \subseteq I$.  We can therefore let $\widetilde{\mathcal{U}}_j = \{U_i \; | \; i \in I_j\}$.  The union

$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^n \widetilde{\mathcal{U}}_j
$$

induces a finite subcover over $K_1 \times \ldots \times K_n$.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is not hard to prove.  But generally on these exams when you don't use what they tell you to assume you are doing something wrong, or missing the point of the question.  Perhaps on this one, this is the best way to go though.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume they want you to prove that the subspace topology induced by the product topology is the same as the product topology of the induced subspace topologies.